# Failed upgrade: troubleshooting 'sudo apt ugrade'

Tags: apt, server, 20.04, updates, update-manager

How to solve this issue as shown in the link?

[image]

I already ran the `sudo apt update --fix-missing` command, but it did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your mirrors, don't use the esm repos if you don't have a subscription with ubuntu, change the repos to the defaults Open the Software & Updates application, then click on the “Download From” drop down box. Click the “Select best server” button to let Ubuntu do the work for you. Then try `sudo apt update`

Comment: I've already followed these instructions previously, but unfortunately, the issue persists. My setting is "Download from" -> "select best server".

Comment: @JohanesPS why are you using the esm repos?

Comment: I have no idea; that's the output I received from the terminal.